# Civilians attacking me

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I've been attacking things close to cities, when villagers try to "help". Then I accidentally hit them and they go aggro on me. So, is there anyway to get them to stop, besides the Calm spell?

Comment: sometimes you've just gotta hit her to show her who is boss!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can **Yield** to them by sheathing your weapon. Note that you may still have a bounty for the assault you've just committed that you'll have to deal with. If you aren't in tight with the Thieves Guild and/or have a low Speechcraft skill, this might end up costing you any stolen items you happen to be carrying.

Comment: I didn't commit a crime, I just was killing bears or other things that came after me in the wild. So sheathing will definitely work if I didn't commit a crime?

Comment: Hitting a civilian - even if you did it accidentally while killing a bear - is often considered an assault, which carries a 40 gold bounty. Sheathing will cause him to end hostilities, but the next time you talk to a guard in that hold, they'll demand that you pay up.

Answer (score 3):

The Imperial power **Voice of the Emperor** or a **calming spell** will make them forgive you. Also, you can sheath your weapon (usually R or Square), this indicates you're not here for fighting, and then it's up to the NPCs AI to determine if you are still a threat.

Comment: He did say he was looking for a solution *other than* 'that one illusion spell'.

Answer (score 0):

When you commit a crime in whatever city you're in, leave for a bit, go adventure, come back but don't talk to any guards (a way to getting as far away from jail cells or paying bounty)

Comment: fails i ment do not talk to guards

Answer (score 0):

Try leaving the village or location where you were attacked, fast travel to another non-nearby location and wait for at least 48 hours, then go back. The villagers should have put down their [torches and pitchforks](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TorchesAndPitchforks) by then and should have calmed down.